# CWinApp object. How To launch this?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC-project that needed to be fixed. I`ve fixed all bugs but during the launcing the programm it throws Access violation Read Location in AfxWinMain(). I searched the web and traced this function and found out that

CWinThread* pThread = AfxGetThread();

```
if(!pThread->InitInstance())//Here pThread is NULL
      //snippet
```

Than i googled it and found this article on MS Blogs:
[Why AfxGetThread() return null](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/06/21/why-afxgetthread-returns-null-in-afxwinmain.aspx)
They advice to create the object `CWinApp` and i've done it too.

```
//Sinippet

    }

CWinApp obj;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildView, CDialog)

//Sinippet
```

So this `NullReferenceExeption`in `AfxWinMain()` disapperared but after launhing nothing happens at all. The `AfxWinMain()` function returns the control without construction of any windows. Help me please to launch it.(if it possible)

P.S: I'm not sure at my MFC knowlege..

P.P.S: I was given to debug this NotConsole Aplication and I have only .h file with class derived from CDialog and .cpp file with programm logic and there is unused `_tmain()` function. There is no any more users' main functions.

Comment: If you are compiling a console application try calling `AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0);` before calling `CWinThread* pThread = AfxGetThread();`.

Comment: Did you run the program with the debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the File, New, Project wizard in Visual Studio to create a new MFC project. Select the "Dialog Based" option for the MFC project. This project should compile and launch without problem. Then you can change the project (in the InitInstance function) to use your CDialog-based class instead of the dialog generated by the wizard.